# Calculate values in a vector based on the elements in another vector in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two vectors: time and event. If one event is 1, the time at the same index should be assigned to `func_for_event1`. Otherwise, it goes to `func_for_event0`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def func_for_event1(t):
    return t + 1

def func_for_event0(t):
    return t - 1

time = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])  # [3.2, 4.2, 1.0, 1.05, 1.8]
event = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None])  # [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

# result: [2.2, 5.2, 2.0, 0.05, 2.8]
# For example, 3.2 should be sent to func_for_event0 because the first element in event is 0.
```

How should I implement this logic in Tensorflow? Say `tf.cond` or `tf.where`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what [`tf.where()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) is for. This code (tested):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def func_for_event1(t):
    return t + 1

def func_for_event0(t):
    return t - 1

time = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None])  # [3.2, 4.2, 1.0, 1.05, 1.8]
event = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None])  # [0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

result = tf.where( tf.equal( 1, event ), func_for_event1( time ), func_for_event0( time ) )
# result: [2.2, 5.2, 2.0, 0.05, 2.8]
# For example, 3.2 should be sent to func_for_event0 because the first element in event is 0.

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run( result, feed_dict = {
        time : np.array( [3.2, 4.2, 1.0, 1.05, 1.8] ),
        event : np.array( [0, 1, 1, 0, 1] )
    } )
    print ( res )
```

outputs:

> [2.2        5.2        2.         0.04999995 2.8       ]

as desired.

Comment: One follow-up question: when I change "t-1" in func_for_event0 to "tf.constant(0.0)", I get "ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 1 and 0 for 'Select' (op: 'Select') with input shapes: [?], [?], []."

Comment: `t` in the function is a tensor with the same shape as `time`, not a single value. `tf.where()` needs two full-sized tensors and it takes the element from one or the other based on the condition. If you want to return zero, do `return tf.zeros_like( t )`.